# Redux enhancer example

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I am new to redux. I would like know how I could create my own enhancer in redux. I didn't find any example to create **enhancer**. To create enhancers, So what arguments do I need to pass and what do I need to return? Is there any rule on creating custom enhancer?

In redux documentation about enhancer, found below two links (no sample or example code)

- [store-enhancer](https://redux.js.org/understanding/thinking-in-redux/glossary#store-enhancer)
- [using store enhancer](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#creating-a-store-with-enhancers)

Redux documentation said that,

> Middleware adds extra functionality to the Redux dispatch function; enhancers add extra functionality to the Redux store. ... A middleware which logs dispatched actions and the resulting new state. An enhancer which logs the time taken for the reducers to process each action.

So, I am not sure that custom middleware and custom enhancer coding rule are the same like below

```
const loggerMiddleware = storeAPI => next => action => {
  console.log('dispatching', action)
  let result = next(action)
  console.log('next state', storeAPI.getState())
  return result
}
```

So, my question is ***how to create custom enhancer?***

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/types/store.ts#L262) is the store enhancer interface

```
export type StoreEnhancer<Ext = {}, StateExt = never> = (
  next: StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<Ext, StateExt>
) => StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<Ext, StateExt>
export type StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<Ext = {}, StateExt = never> = <
  S = any,
  A extends Action = AnyAction
>(
  reducer: Reducer<S, A>,
  preloadedState?: PreloadedState<S>
) => Store<ExtendState<S, StateExt>, A, StateExt, Ext> & Ext
```

`enhancers` are high-order functions that take `createStore` and return a new enhanced version of `createStore`. Take a look at this sample implementation.

```
const ourAwesomeEnhancer = createStore => (reducer, initialState, enhancer) => {
  const store = createStore(monitoredReducer, initialState, enhancer);
  //  add enhancer logic

  return {
    ...store
    //   you can override the some store properties or add new ones
  };
};
```

There is an example in [official doc](https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store#enhancersmonitorreducerjs):

```js
const round = number => Math.round(number * 100) / 100

const monitorReducerEnhancer = createStore => (
  reducer,
  initialState,
  enhancer
) => {
  const monitoredReducer = (state, action) => {
    const start = performance.now()
    const newState = reducer(state, action)
    const end = performance.now()
    const diff = round(end - start)

    console.log('reducer process time:', diff)

    return newState
  }

  return createStore(monitoredReducer, initialState, enhancer)
}

export default monitorReducerEnhancer
```

Comment: with one correction i believe, `ourAwesomeEnhancer` is not returning inner function with 3 arguments such as: `(reducer, initialState, enhancer)` rather just with two as: `(reducer, initialState)`, and one of the first thing i believe in `createStore` function is
`if enhancer is defined => return enhancer(createStore)(reducer, initialState)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's some examples in the official docs https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-fundamentals-example-app/blob/7d17ec4fa5d46c839adfd8c716ccfedaf365f7c0/src/exampleAddons/enhancers.js

because it is a higher order function, you can do something llike the following:

```
./src/store.js  

import { createStore } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './reducer'
import { sayHiOnDispatch, includeMeaningOfLife } from './exampleAddons/enhancers'


const ModifiedCreateStore = sayHiOnDispatch(createStore);
const ModifiedCreateStore2 = includeMeaningOfLife(ModifiedCreateStore);
const store = ModifiedCreateStore2(rootReducer, undefined, sayHiOnDispatch);
//getState will add 'meaningOfLife: 42' and Hi will be logged two times on dispatch
//const store = createStore(rootReducer, undefined, sayHiOnDispatch)

export default store
```